# Varnish 4.0 problems - Service running, and Listening but not responding

Tags: server, apt, varnish

this is the first time Ive installed varnish 4.0 - I suspect config etc is relatively simple and have installed varnish on a few other servers. However I can't get Varnish to respond. I've setup with Pound (:443), and currently I have Apache running behind (:8090), 8090 responds, not bothering with Pound just yet but Port :80 doesn't respond.

```
#: netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1450/pound
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6876/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6876/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1379/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6876/varnishd
```

Appears to be configured as I would expect, I havn't messed with default.vcl to much - as want it simply to respond which it isn't no results in varnishtop/varnishlog.

I think I may have more packages than I need?, Ive compared this install with another server (varnish 3.0) and the number of Varnish packages appears to be much longer by comparison.. ?

```
#:/etc/varnish# apt-cache policy libvarnishapi1
libvarnishapi1:
  Installed: 4.1.3-1~jessie
  Candidate: 4.1.3-1~jessie
  Version table:
 *** 4.1.3-1~jessie 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian jessie/varnish-4.1 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.1.2-2~jessie 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian jessie/varnish-4.1 amd64 Packages
     4.1.2-1~jessie 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian jessie/varnish-4.1 amd64 Packages
     4.1.1-1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
     4.1.1-1~jessie 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian jessie/varnish-4.1 amd64 Packages
     4.1.0-1~jessie 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian jessie/varnish-4.1 amd64 *Packages
     3.0.7-1~lucid 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.6-1~lucid 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.5-1~lucid 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.4-1~lucid 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.3-1~lucid 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.2-1~1lucid1 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64 Packages
     3.0.1-1~lucid1 500
        500 http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu lucid/varnish-3.0 amd64* Packages
```

Does that list, cause any issues? I attempted to Purge varnish + all config and that has allowed more functionality (i.e. Starting Varnish) If so how do I clear the packages sources properly? as Already tried once and the list above didn't change?

Thanks

Update:

ps aux | grep varnish Shows three processes:

```
vcache    7518  0.0  1.1 120836  7544 ?        Ss   02:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
vcache    7532  0.2 13.7 267804 94072 ?        Sl   02:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/...
root      7810  0.0  0.1  12944  1084 pts/0    S+   02:32   0:00 grep --color=auto varnish
```

Says there should only be two?
deshack.net/how-to-varnish-listen-port-80-systemd/

Comment: Just compiled the vcl file, and appears to be conflicting with something

#varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl                                         Error: Cannot open socket: :80: Address already in use

Comment: Try ```telnet localhost 80``` then disable services one after another (apache, varnish) to find out which one is taking over port 80.

Comment: Hello Daniel, have rebuilt another server to test, having the same problem made sure not to add varnish 3.0 repo. wget 127.0.0.1:80 downloads the IIS default page which is expected without the domain. So is working internally but not externally, have checked IP Tables, Listening Ports and Azure Firewall - can't workout whats missing, also changed localhost references to 127.0.0.1 just in case but works the same.

Comment: # telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

This is being closed for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out - in Azure endpoints I had selected Floating IP address Enabled for :80, set to disabled and is now working as expected.